# I do not know how to test the create query builder

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony4, doctrine-mongodb, prophecy

I'm trying to test the all method of a repository, but I do not know how to do the test, I want to use Profecy. I'm using [DoctrineMongoDBBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html).

Entity

```
class UsuarioEntidade{
/**
 * @MongoDB\Id
 */
protected $usuId;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="string", name="usua_nome")
 */
protected $usuNome;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="string", name="usua_telefone")
 */
protected $usuTelefone;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="string", name="usua_email")
 */
protected $usuEmail;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="string", name="usua_imagem_perfil")
 */
protected $usuImagemPerfil;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="date")
 */
protected $createdAt;

##get and set
```

Repository

```
class UsuarioRepositorio
{
protected $dm;

public function __construct(DocumentManager $documentManager)
{
    $this->dm = $documentManager;
}
public function all(array $input = null)
{
    $usuario = UsuarioEntidade::class;

    $all = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder($usuario);     

    return $all->getQuery();
}
```

This is the test that I do not know how to perform based on the repository class.

```
class UsuarioRepositorioTest extends TestCase
{

protected $repositorio;

protected $documento;

public function setUp()
{
    $this->documento = $this->prophesize(DocumentManager::class);

    $this->repositorio = new UsuarioRepositorio($this->documento->reveal());
}
public function testObtendoTodosOsDados()
{
    $output = $this->usuario();
    $this->documento->createQueryBuilder(UsuarioEntidade::class)->willReturn($output)->shouldBeCalled();

    $all = $this->repositorio->all();

    $this->assertEquals($output, $all);
}

protected function usuario()
    {
        $usuarioEntidade = new UsuarioEntidade();
        $usuarioEntidade->setUsuNome('Humanos');
        $usuarioEntidade->setUsuTelefone('89855236554');
        $usuarioEntidade->setUsuEmail('mano@email.com');
        $usuarioEntidade->setUsuImagemPerfil('/application/sam/tests/Usuario/ImagemPerfil/sam.png');

        $data = new \DateTime();
        $usuarioEntidade->setCreatedAt($data->format('Y-m-d'));

        return $usuarioEntidade;
    }
```

I do not know how to mock the method "getQuery()".
This error always occurs: 
Error: Call to a member function getQuery() on array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the code is that your `createQUeryBuilder()` expectation returns an array and you are trying to call a function on that array.

You have to mock a `QueryBuilder` object and set up an expectation for its `getQuery()` function to return your desired output. The QueryBuilder mock has to be returned when you set up the expectation for the DocumentManager `createQueryBuilder()` function.

Something like this:

```
public function testObtendoTodosOsDados()
{
    $output = $this->usuario();

    $mockQueryBuilder = $this->prophesize(QueryBuilder::class); // Remember to import the proper QueryBuilder namespace

    $mockQueryBuilder->getQuery()->willReturn($output)->shouldBeCalled();

    $this->documento->createQueryBuilder(UsuarioEntidade::class)->willReturn($mockQueryBuilder)->shouldBeCalled();

    $all = $this->repositorio->all();

    $this->assertEquals($output, $all);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!